# Prove that if $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is monotonic decreasing and $f$ is bounded, then $\lim\limits_{x\to b^{-}}f(x)=\inf_{x\in (a, b)}f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have two questions with respect to this exercise, first to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to b^{-}}f(x)=\inf_{x\in (a, b)}f(x)=c$
i.e., for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in[a, b]$ if $\delta>b-x>0$ then $|f(x)-c|<\epsilon$.

Let any $\epsilon >0$ by the property of approximation of the infimum there exists $x_{0}\in [a, b]$ such that $f(x_{0})<c+\epsilon$. Let $\delta=b-x_{0}$, note that if $\delta>b-x$ then $a\leq x_{0} <x \leq b $, as $f$ is decreasing then $f(x_{0})\geq f(x)$ from where $c+\epsilon>f(x)$

Now, by properties of the infimum $c \leq f(x)$ for all $x\in (a, b)$ and $c-\epsilon <f(x)$; whereby $c-\epsilon<f(x)<c+\epsilon$ this is $|f(x)-c|<\epsilon$.

Well, this is correct, would you correct anything?

Secondly, I wonder if there is a monotonic decreasing function in $(a, b)$ for which such a limit $\lim\limits_{x\to b^{-}}f(x)$ does not exist.

Any help? I appreciate it!

Comment: For a solution-verification question, you must put the corresponding tag and specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Comment: As for your second question, it is answered in this duplicate: [Limit of a Monotonic Increasing and Non-Bounded Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413486/limit-of-a-monotonic-increasing-and-non-bounded-function). But please next time focus on one question per post.

Comment: Here is a duplicate (mutatis mutandis) of your proof: [$f$ is a monotonic increasing function. Prove $\lim_{x\to x_{{0}^{+}}} f(x)= \inf_{x>x_0} f(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2579927).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is correct. Another approach is to show

$$\lim\limits_{x\to b^{-}}f(x)\ge\inf_{x\in (a, b)}f(x)\cap \lim\limits_{x\to b^{-}}f(x)\le\inf_{x\in (a, b)}f(x)$$

For the second part, you can take some function like the shape of $y=\frac{1}x, x<0$ and shift rightwards by $b$, i.e.
$f(x)=\frac{1}{x-b}$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{x-b}$ is not bounded in $(a,b)$. Anyway the limit in $b$ equals $inf$ in $(a,b)$ (both are $-\infty$). Since the limit in $b$ does not depend from $f(b)$, if the $\inf$ is taken in $[a,b]$, it can be different by the limit in $b$.